# Getting a specific tag object using django-taggit

Tags: python, django

I am using [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) to manage the tags in my app. I am able to pull the tagged items like this:

```
photos = Photo.objects.filter(
    Q(status = 1) & Q(tags__id__in=[id])
).order_by('-position')
```

What I want to get is the current tag name. How can I do that?

Comment: assuming tags are associated with photo then `photo.tags.all()`

Comment: @Aamir Adnan I just want the current tag, not all tags associated with the object.

Comment: What do you mean "current tag"?

Comment: @Enrico The tag I am using to pull the photos associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `tags__id__in` which means you know the tag ids?. So just get them directly.

```
tags = Tags.objects.filter(id__in=[ids])
for tag in tags:
    print tag.name
```

Alternately using your mentioned query (I am excluding `tags__id__in` from your query)

```
photos = Photo.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-position')
for photo in photos:
    tags = photo.tags.all()
    for tag in tags:
        print tag.name
```